dial tcp: lookup db on x.x.x.x:5433: no such host
I have a simple docker file that contains a database and is perfectly deployed, but when connecting to the database from outside, the following error is displayed:
dial tcp: lookup db on x.x.x.x:53: no such host

docker-compose:
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "tickets"
      POSTGRES_USER: "tickets"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "tickets"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata:

main.go:
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    conf := DBConfig{
        Driver:   "postgres",
        Host:     "db",
        Port:     "5432",
        Username: "tickets",
        Dbname:   "tickets",
        Password: "tickets",
    }
    dataBase, _ := NewDB(conf)
    fmt.Println(dataBase.DB)
}

type DBConfig struct {
    Driver   string `mapstructure:"driver"`
    Host     string `mapstructure:"host"`
    Port     string `mapstructure:"port"`
    Username string `mapstructure:"username"`
    Password string `mapstructure:"password"`
    Dbname   string `mapstructure:"dbname"`
    logger   *logrus.Logger
}

func NewDB(config DBConfig) (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    source := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", config.Host, config.Port, config.Username, config.Dbname)
    fmt.Println("Connecting to database with source: " + source)

    conn, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", source)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    err = conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}


Os: Rocky Linux 9.4
there may be a problem with my dns settings, but I have no idea how to set it up correctly. I found etc/resolv.conf on my computer, but this address was already listed there. Restarting docker did not give any results either. I tried user: localhost, but then it requires a password, and when creating a new user and granting him rights inside the container, the password is incorrect

*Connecting to the database from the outside means connecting to it from the same computer where this container is running.(connection is not between containers)
*When transferring as a host localhost 127.0.0..., as I wrote above, an error pops up about incorrect authentication.(there is a screenshot above) I used docker exec to go inside the container under the tickets user, checked if such a user really exists

Does it work with the ipaddress? Eg set host to localhost eg. 127.0.0.1?

Sounds like two separate errors.  The first one is not about postgresql specifically, but just about how docker fakes DNS.  I suspect the problem would be with the container where go is running, not the one where postgresql is running.  For the second one, what does "when creating a new user and granting him rights inside the container" mean?  Is that part of the docker file, or is that some other unshown action?

What does "connecting to the database from outside" mean exactly? On the same machine but from outside Docker? Or from another machine?

Someone edited your title in a way which I think is inaccurate.  The error is on port 53 (DNS port) not 5433 (a common secondary postgresql port), correct?

source := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", config.Host, config.Port, config.Username, config.Dbname)

The password is missing in your connection string. Update it to:
source := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", config.Host, config.Port, config.Username, config.Password, config.Dbname)                                                 

Including the password ensures that the authentication process can be completed.

lookup db on x.x.x.x:53: no such host - how could that error be resolved through adding the password?

sorry ,i answered for the authentication error .

Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it
